# why windows terminal looks bad when typing ls

Tags: powershell, terminal

I have a question, in my windows terminal - powershell when it is in the standard size and I try to list the files in a folder does not look good, but when the window is maximized if you manage to see well, why this occurs and is there any way to fix it?

Example

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to Powershell Settings, Your Profile, and set font size, color and so on. That is what I do,

Comment: I see nothing odd about the Windows Terminal in those screenshots except for the physical dimensions of the window in the first screenshot

Comment: in wls ubuntu independent of the size the files are not cluttered as in the first image, that's the difference. How can I modify that if there is any configuration

Comment: As I noted, settings like Font Size are in the Default Profile and under Settings.

Comment: Is it worth it (to me) to post an answer for you?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "looks good"? Do you mean it does not look the way you expect, that the information is incorrect, something else? "Looks good" doesn't mean anything concrete and so does not help any of us understand you, or help anyone else who may be having similar issues. You should edit this question to make it more specific and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in wls ubuntu independent of the size the files are not cluttered as in the first image, that's the difference.

The actual difference is that PowerShell `ls` is not Ubuntu `ls` at all.

The `ls` command found in PowerShell is *completely different* from that on Linux systems. It's not a clone of Linux 'ls' – it's really an alias to PowerShell's own `gci` or `Get-ChildItem` command, which uses the standard table formatting built into PowerShell (i.e. an implicit `ft` or `Format-Table` is being done).

As a workaround, try `ls | ft name` to limit output to only that column, or `| ft mode,name` to include multiple columns. (You can remove the built-in alias and create a custom function.)

The screenshot is probably of Windows PowerShell 5; the new PowerShell 7 (installable separately) handles table output somewhat differently and appears to be more compact. (Though not necessarily *better* – if the window is too narrow, PS 7 seems to simply discard columns from the right, resulting in a directory list that has no filenames at all...)

There *are* Windows ports of the Linux 'ls', but you need to install them separately; MSYS (comes with Git for Windows) and Cygwin are the usual options.